# SUM first table on second CATEGORY table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sum

I have a table ProdByCat

```
CatID      ProductID 
---------------------------
Food        Beans
Food        Corn
Food        Peas
Drink       Juice
Drink       Wine
```

And another table Purchases

```
Region        ProductID   Cost
-----------------------------
North         Beans       5
South         Beans       5
West          Beans       5
North         Corn        5
North         Peas        5 
West          Wine        10
West          Juice       10
```

What I'd like is to have a table that returns

```
Region     CatID   TotalCost
-----------------------------
North      Food    15
South      Food    5
West       Food    5
West       Drink   20
```

I am certain that I am over complicating it. This is the direction that I am traveling:

```
select P.Region, Y.CatID, SUM(P.Cost) As 'TotalCost'
from Purchases As P, 
(   select distinct(A.CatID), 
    Includes=( stuff ( 
         select ''''+ ProductID + ''','  
         from ProdByCat B
         where B.CatID = A.CatID
         order by ProductID
         for xml path ('')
         ),1,1,'')
    from ProdByCat A
) Y
where ProductID in (Y.Includes)
group by P.Region, Y.CatID
```

It's fubar'd. Syntactically, it works but returns an empty set.

My thought was that if I used the xml path function, I could create an include list that if the ProductID existed in, would allow me to create a sum.

Comment: Why the `Drink` has the region `North`?

Comment: `Y.Includes LIKE'%' + CAST(ProductID as NVARCHAR(32)) + '%'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets create the test data:

```
DECLARE @ProdByCat TABLE
(
    CatID VARCHAR(10),
    ProductID VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @ProdByCat
( CatID, ProductID )
VALUES
('Food'        ,'Beans'),
('Food'        ,'Corn'),
('Food'        ,'Peas'),
('Drink'       ,'Juice'),
('Drink'       ,'Wine');

DECLARE @Purchases TABLE
(
    Region VARCHAR(10),
    ProductID VARCHAR(10),
    Cost int
)

INSERT INTO @Purchases
( Region, ProductID, Cost )
VALUES
('North',         'Beans',       5),
('South',         'Beans',       5),
('West',          'Beans',       5),
('North',         'Corn',        5),
('North',         'Peas',        5),
('West',          'Wine',        10),
('West',          'Juice',       10);
```

Now we'll do a join and a group by to get the cost of each category:

```
SELECT p.Region, pc.CatId, SUM(COST) AS Cost 
FROM @Purchases p
INNER JOIN @ProdByCat pc
    ON p.ProductID = pc.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Region, pc.CatID
ORDER BY p.Region, pc.CatID DESC
```

Output:

```
Region  CatId   Cost
North   Food    15
South   Food    5
West    Food    5
West    Drink   20
```

Answer (score 3):

You're right. You are over complicating it. It can be much simpler:

```
SELECT p.Region, pbc.CatID, SUM(p.Cost) AS TotalCost
    FROM Purchases p
        INNER JOIN ProdByCat pbc
            ON p.ProductID = pbc.ProductID
    GROUP BY p.Region, pbc.CatID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like just `Group by` with `Sum` aggregate should work. Try this.

There is a mistake in your expected result last row should be `West Drink 20`. Region should be `West` instead of `North`

```
SELECT Region,
       CatID,
       Sum(cost) TotalCost
FROM   ProdByCat A
       JOIN Purchases b
         ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
GROUP  BY Region,
          CatID
```

Answer (score 1):

To yield the table you described, you just need an inner join and a group by

```
select 
    Region = p.Region,
    CatID = c.CatID,
    TotalCost = sum(Cost)
from #ProdByCat c
inner join #Purchases p
    on c.ProductID = p.ProductID
group by p.Region, c.CatID
```

But your for xml code makes it sound like you're looking to have a delimited list of products associated with each group. If that's what you need, let me know.